# Is it proper and what's the proper way to close real beginner questions?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I just encountered [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/8263622?filter-closereason=offtopic) about a question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30551193/make-a-loop-in-swift) being off-topic. The specific reason given was that

> This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope
>   defined in the [help/on-topic].

On the one hand the question is a real beginner one, and asks how to use a loop to run a code piece 5 times. On the other hand, I tried to find a proper close reason, and couldn't quite find one. And I didn't want to abuse the system by closing it as `too broad` or `unclear what you are asking`. The person stated the problem quite clearly, and it is a programming issue.

The only thing I can think of is maybe it has been asked before.

I believe the person asking really don't know although most programmers know. But is that a sufficient reason for closing it?

-- Clarification --

I don't think what I asked is the said duplicate, which speaks to down-voting beginner questions. I asked/mentioned nothing about whether it is justifiable to downvote it (although it was downvoted 5 times within 2 hours). What I am asking is whether it is justifiable to close it (since I saw it in a close-review); and if so, on what grounds.

Comment: It's related. I am specifically interested in finding a close reason.

Comment: There is no close reason.

Comment: And the one people loved to abuse for that is no longer with us.

Comment: Nope, sorry, you are not the target demographic for the StackExchange company and its investors.  You cannot say what you care about but is not in their interest, blocked by the carefully crafted approved speech in the close dialog.  You can't get ahead of a would-be programmer without any meaningful education or an expensive student loan to pay off, you are not what they are looking for.  They only care about that cheap guy having a shot at doing the job he was asked to do.  That's what pays the bills.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate. Both said duplicate was about down-voting beginner questions. I am asking about closing them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If a question does not fit a close reason, then it shouldn't be closed using that reason. There is no "this is a beginner question" close reason.

That being said, when you hover over the downvote button it says, "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful." If you feel that a question about how to perform a for loop in a particular language does not show research effort (considering, for instance, most tutorials would make it to for loops pretty quickly), then this could be a good option.